# Can no longer select objects by clicking them

Tags: objects, selection-tools, object-mode

So, it seems like I have accidentally changed a selection-setting in a project of mine. I can no longer select objects by simply clicking on them, or drawing a box around them by way of box select. Radius or Lasso select do not appear to work, either.

This applies to geometric objects (as those shown in the image) as well as to lights, cameras, and armatures. This issue appears only in this particular project, across all its scenes (even those I have not edited since before the issue started occuring). If I create a new project, the issue does not occur and selecting works as I'm used to.

One notable factor that leads me to believe that I have accidentally activated a certain mode or layer is that all objects in my scene are now showing strange new dots/control points (see image). These dots I can select and even manipulate (e.g. translate), but that does not seem to change anything about the appearance or position of the object itself. Also notable is that this issue occurs only in Object Mode and Pose Mode. Edit mode works as normal.

[image: Example of mysterious dots]

Comment: Can you select or delete them from Outliner? The quicker way is to keep one object in a scene and upload file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to let us see.

Comment: One thing I do from time to time if I suspect there is some problem with settings is to  select and copy everything, open a new project (delete light, cube and camera), and then paste everything into the new project. You won't have the world configuration you set up in the first project, but it can be a good way to test if the problem is from an accidental configuration change.

Comment: @Hoshi would be helpful to post the simplified file anyway to know what these symptoms means, sometimes it can be easier to switch a checkbox than to port all scene.